# Verifying an equivalence using propositional logic theorems

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How to verify the following equivalence:

$ \alpha_1 \to \alpha_2 \to ... \to \alpha_n \equiv \alpha_1 \land \alpha_2 \land  ... \alpha_{n-1} \to \alpha_n $

How should I use the deduction theorem in order to verify this expression?

Comment: What's easiest here depends a lot on which tools you have to work with. If you know that $a\to b$ is equivalent to $\neg a \lor b$, it should be fairly simple to prove by induction on $n$ that each of your formulas is separately equivalent to $\neg a_1\lor \neg a_2\lor \cdots \lor \neg a_{n-1} \lor a_n$, and therefore to each other.

Comment: I could do that! Thanks for the simple answer! But, is it possible using the deduction theorem in some part of the verification ? (question edited, sorry).

Comment: It would be nice if the formulas had some parentheses in them.

Comment: @LuizS.: Using the deduction theorem essentially corresponds to working in natural deduction, and you can certainly (and easily!) derive the two sides of your equivalence from each other with natural deduction. Converting that argument to one that only speaks about a Hilbert-style proof system plus the deduction theorem ought to be doable, though I fear getting all the details right without obscuring the basic idea would be somewhat tedious.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Hmm if we have the deduction (meta)-theorem, we can do what I propose in my answer as cleanly as in natural deduction. The only difference is that we're working in the meta-system as opposed to the formal system itself.

Comment: @user21820: That's right as far as the _substance_ goes. Perhaps I'm unreasonably worried about which _style_ would be accepted in a context where one knows the DT but insists on treating it purely as a metatheorem rather than a rule that can be used in proofs.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Ah yes indeed one should make it clear in the solution, that we're reasoning about provability (the **existence** of a proof), and not explicitly providing one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the deduction theorem repeatedly to get an equivalence between the chain of implications and the ability to prove the final consequent from the set of antecedents. Then use the $\land$ rules to get an equivalence between provability from a finite set and provability from the conjunction of the set. Finally use the deduction theorem once to get between provability from a conjunction and provability of an implication from the conjunction.